# How to load configurations in spring application from two sources where configuration from first source is required to load second one

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have spring based java application, The application support different databases and can be deployed on various containers. We have two type of configuration sources:
- Properties file: Bare minimum configuration to start the application. i.e application datasource JNDI name and database type.
- Config stored in DB as JSON/ hocon: Other configurations used by application.

what is the best way to have it implemented in spring context file, so that these configurations can be made available to the spring beans. The key problem here is to extract configuration from DB I need values from properties file (to locate the datasource).

Is to possible to have overriding feature where properties file have some default configurations, which are overridden by configuration loaded from DB. I have tried using multiple properties file, but not sure how I can have two property sources.

Comment: If you need to do very over engineered overcomplex things, i suggest you dont use a framework thats designed to be used in certain ways. Keep it simple.

Comment: Why do you think it is over engineering, Probably the explanation is not precise. My requirement is to load properties from some central database/ central configuration service and to reach out to central repository I need some properties.  Please advice.